# Android - Async downloads all files under one name

Tags: android

I'm using Async to download all the files I need to one area (walkfaster.mod adventure.mod and climbing.mod) and the links are downloading the correct file, but it saves it all under the name walkfaster.mod. Heres my code:

```
package com.dogger20011.mcpemodlocater;



public class v090 extends Activity {

public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private Button startBtn;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.v090);
    startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startDownload(v);
        }
    });

    startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            startDownload(v);
        }
    });

    startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            startDownload(v);
        }
    });
}


private void startDownload(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button2:
    String url = "https://docs.google.com/uc?
authuser=0&id=0B6ocq4LWhNJkZ2gyazVqNlZjcDg&export=download";
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
    break;

    case R.id.button3:
        String url1 = "https://docs.google.com/uc? 
authuser=0&id=0B6ocq4LWhNJkMmUwcWhraU5SUkU&export=download";
        new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url1);
        break;

    case R.id.button4:
        String url2 = "https://docs.google.com/uc?     
authuser=0&id=0B6ocq4LWhNJkX01aUGlxcFA0cU0&export=download";
        new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url2);
        break;
    }
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        return mProgressDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
}

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
    int count;

try {

URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
conexion.connect();

int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream output = new  FileOutputStream
("/sdcard/Android/data/com.snowbound.pockettool.free/Patches/walkfaster");

byte data[] = new byte[1024];

long total = 0;

    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += count;
        publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
        output.write(data, 0, count);
    }

    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();  

} catch (Exception e) {}
return null; }


private void execute(URL url, URL url1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void myClickHandler(View v){
    Intent i3 = new Intent(v090.this, server_255.class);
    startActivity(i3);
    }
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do something like this, pass the file name with the url `new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url, "myFile1");` where `myFile1` is file name. Then you can retrieve this name using `aurl[1]` in `doInBackground` method.

Here is the sample,

```
private void startDownload(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button2:
    String url = "https://docs.google.com/uc?
authuser=0&id=0B6ocq4LWhNJkZ2gyazVqNlZjcDg&export=download";
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url, "myFile1");
    break;

    case R.id.button3:
        String url1 = "https://docs.google.com/uc? 
authuser=0&id=0B6ocq4LWhNJkMmUwcWhraU5SUkU&export=download";
        new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url1, "myFile2");
        break;

    case R.id.button4:
        String url2 = "https://docs.google.com/uc?     
authuser=0&id=0B6ocq4LWhNJkX01aUGlxcFA0cU0&export=download";
        new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url2, "myFile3");
        break;
    }
}
```

And replace this line

```
OutputStream output = new  FileOutputStream
("/sdcard/Android/data/com.snowbound.pockettool.free/Patches/walkfaster");
```

by

```
OutputStream output = new  FileOutputStream
("/sdcard/Android/data/com.snowbound.pockettool.free/Patches/"+ aurl[1]);
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Great job at explaining too!